# How can we sequentially move the same WAR file from Test to Beta to Live in separate release processes using Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have three environments: Test, Beta, and Live. For the Test release, we need to generate a WAR file and perform the release. Once a WAR file is successfully released in the Test environment, it should be considered for the Beta release. Similarly, once a WAR file is successfully released in the Beta environment, it should be considered for the Live release. Each of these releases (Test, Beta, and Live) is initiated as a separate manual process. How can we achieve this in Azure Pipelines?